# Using mobile web view on desktop shows invalid vertical scroll

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, mobile-web

When creating new or opening existing post to edit using mobile view and being on desktop post body block contains vertical scrollbar with hidden top part:

> [image: mobile-scroll-on-desktop]:

Top of the scrollbar is hidden under "Add picture" bar.

Tested in FF, Chrome. Windows 7.

On the real mobile devices (tablet, phone) there is no scrollbars at all and page looks fine.

Comment: It doesn't harm any functionality. It's in something not meant to be used (mobile view is, well, meant for mobile devices). All in all, one of the most minor bugs that can exist.

Comment: Agree with @ShadowWizard. A scroll bar is always attached to the edge of a scrolling component and is always as tall (wide) as the component's height (width). So maybe for compatibility concerns the SE made the "Add picture" toolbar overlay (part of) the input field, that's OK.

Comment: As long as it works correctly on *mobile*. We don't correct bugs for a mobile site that only appear on desktop.

Comment: @animuson what about another [bugzzz](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=User%3A339911+%5Bbug%5D+%5Bmobile-web%5D+-%5Bstatus-*%5D)?

Comment: @iBug actually that wasn't what I mean. I agree this is a bug, just not worth fixing.